# VB.Net update database table that has auto-increment column

Tags: vb.net, syntax, adapter, auto-increment

I have vb.net application that loads data from a table in access database. This table has a primary key ID which is an auto-increment column. I update the data table with the following code:

```
daAdapter.Update(dsOptions.Tables("notes"))
```

But the following error appears: "Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement"
How can I solve that?  [image]

Comment: What is sql command used to initialize the daAdapter? "SELECT ???? FROM ????"?

Comment: yes: sql="select * from notes" and then fill a dataset with the results. and set this table as the datasource for a datagridview

Comment: Sorry, but I think that probably in your notes table there is a field with a reserved name. Could you tell me what are the column names of the table notes? You could add, just before the call to update the following line `Console.WriteLine(daAdapter.InsertCommand.CommandText)` and check the result on the output window

Comment: I tried to use you code but It says Object reference not set to an instance of an object!

Comment: DESC and Type are a reserved keywords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your table contains [Reserved Keywords](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx) like DESC and TYPE is necessary to inform the OleDbDataAdapter to use special characters to isolate the column names.

For example. Supposing that you build the adapter in this way

```
 Using con = new OleDbConnection(.....)
 Using cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM NOTES", con
   con.Open
   daAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
   Dim builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(daAdapter)
   builder.QuotePrefix = "["
   builder.QuoteSuffic = "]"
   daAdapter.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand()
   .... rest of the code that fills the grid
```

Now when you try to call the method Update for the OleDbDataAdapter called `daAdapter` the InserCommand text will be something like this

```
 INSERT INTO [NOTES] ([soccerID], [Type], [Desc]) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

The presence of the square brackets prevents the syntax error. Notice also that if you update your rows in a different method then you need to have the variable `daAdapter` declare at the global level

Comment: Thats right, it solves the problem. So whenever I have reserved keywords I must use [] or builder.QuotePrefix = "["
   builder.QuoteSuffic = "]"
   daAdapter.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand().

Comment: Or even better to avoid using reserved words

Comment: That's the first thing to do if it is still possible. Sometimes, when you have a large application, it's too late and too costly